# Angular 2 Project hosting

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I created angular 2 app using angularcli and now I need to check it in the live server my question is,

```
1. do I have export whole project or what are the option I have?.
2. Can we run it in apache 2 server or we need to use specific server?.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is no need to deploy the source code of your app. You can run the built object files under an Apache server.

`ng build --prod` or `ng build --prod --aot` will build your project into the dist folder. Simply deploy the content of the dist folder to your Apache server.

Comment: what about node module?.

Comment: You don't need node_modules if you want to serve your app from an Apache server after it has been built.

Comment: I also used vaadin polymer element in my project they are in the bower file what gone do with that?.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the app simply using:

```
ng serve
```

The app will start running at `http://localhost:4200/`. Specify custom host and port as:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201
```

Comment: No I need to run my app in remote server man. local machine it run without problem.